# Why hibernate doesn't create table and schema

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using spring-boot and postgreSQL to develop basic restful service. I try to create table by using JPA, here is the application.properties file

```
# Disable feature detection by this undocumented parameter. Check the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServiceImpl.configure method for more details.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

#Default port set
#PostrgreSQL connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=123456789

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
#create/create-drop/update/
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

here is the entity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User", schema = "public")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    String userName;

    @Column(name = "USERSURNAME")
    String userSurName;

    @Column(name = "USERJOB")
    String userJob;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserSurName() {
        return userSurName;
    }

    public void setUserSurName(String userSurName) {
        this.userSurName = userSurName;
    }

    public String getUserJob() {
        return userJob;
    }

    public void setUserJob(String userJob) {
        this.userJob = userJob;
    }
}
```

when I run the application, I am expecting User table must be created. But there is no table or schema.
I can not find any error.

here is the log.

```
2018-07-25 11:31:11.139  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] com.app.service.DemoApplication        : Starting DemoApplication on S00 with PID 10264 (D:\JAVA\WEBZEROWORKSPACE\webzeroproject\target\classes started by s00 in D:\JAVA\WEBZEROWORKSPACE\webzeroproject)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.140  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] com.app.service.DemoApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-25 11:31:11.144  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@477d52e0: startup date [Wed Jul 25 11:31:11 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-25 11:31:11.413  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dd8984d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.491  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.491  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.491  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-25 11:31:11.517  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-25 11:31:11.518  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 374 ms
2018-07-25 11:31:11.542  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.542  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.542  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.542  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.542  INFO 10264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.576  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2018-07-25 11:31:11.618  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2018-07-25 11:31:11.618  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-25 11:31:11.618  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.618  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-07-25 11:31:11.618  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2018-07-25 11:31:11.618  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@1cb89f80
2018-07-25 11:31:11.680  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-25 11:31:11.700  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.762  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@477d52e0: startup date [Wed Jul 25 11:31:11 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-25 11:31:11.784  WARN 10264 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-07-25 11:31:11.785  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{user}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.sihab.service.CommonRestController.deleteUser(java.lang.Long)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.785  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{user}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.sihab.model.User com.sihab.service.CommonRestController.getUser(java.lang.Long)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.785  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.785  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.801  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.801  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.840  WARN 10264 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.918  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-07-25 11:31:11.951  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-25 11:31:11.952  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-07-25 11:31:11.958  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-07-25 11:31:11.971  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-07-25 11:31:11.972  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] com.sihab.service.DemoApplication        : Started DemoApplication in 0.856 seconds (JVM running for 1978.331)
2018-07-25 11:31:11.979  INFO 10264 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
```

Edit: Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>webzero</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <description>web project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <name>webtest</name>
</project>
```

Comment: I found the problem. My entity package was at the same level with my application class, I moved it and springboot application created that entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same issue but couldn't, here are my steps:

- Go to https://start.spring.io and create a demo project with JPA ,
  Postgres Dependencies with 1.5.14 version of Spring boot.
- Add User Class to the same package where the @SpringBootApplication
  class has been placed.
- Updated Application.properties with the same properties(Updated DB
  details).

Here are the logs hibernate specific:

> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl
>   schema export
>
> Hibernate: drop table if exists public.user cascade
>
> Hibernate: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
>
> Hibernate: create table public.user (id int8 not null, userjob
>   varchar(255), username  varchar(255), usersurname varchar(255),
>   primary key (id))
>
> Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1

**My Pom.xml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

You can post your pom.xml if you still face issues after the above instructions.

If you want to place the entity classes in a different package from where your SpringBoot Application is placed , you can use do that by providing path of your entities by annotating your SpringBootApplication with

```
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"package-name"} )
```

More info at https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-entity-scan

Comment: I followed same way, my pom.xml is same like yours but still no table and schema

Comment: @sakirow , Updated my answer to be able to use different package name than the one where spring boot application is placed.